# Escape certain html tags in a string

Tags: php

I need to escape all html tags but with some exception like: <b>, <font> etc

For example:

```
 Hello <b>world</b>. How are <span>you</span>?
```

Will result in: Hello **world**. How are you <span>you</span>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to manipulate certain HTML tags in my experience is to use a DOM parser like [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), however this can be a bit tricky to setup and even a bit overkill for your application. If I was to do it all again I would use a different format (like wiki format, or bb code) and not HTML, that way you can convert your own, simple tags to HTML and you have full control over the output.

Back to the question in hand, A quick solution for you would be to use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) and pass a second argument of a tag whitelist - although this isn't 100% perfect/safe for out putting HTML, so in the long run you should use either a DOM parser or not permit HTML input.

Comment: I dont want to strip the tags, i want to escape them. Look at my example, the span tag is still there but its escaped meaning that <span> will show

Comment: If you want to go about messing around with some HTML tags and not others, I would seriously reconsider how/why you are doing this because you will **never** be able to accurately or safely parse the DOM with regular expressions. For styling I would use custom tags and then just escape **all** HTML.

Comment: Yeah, i cant use custom tags because the messages come from an email filter etc ... its complicated. I resolved the problem with a simple preg_replace. Thanks for the suport.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://htmlpurifier.org

I'd also take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Answer (score 0):

php has a function `strip_tags`, i think it will be exactly what you are looking for [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: strip_tags is not safe, just look at the warnings.

Comment: @Peeter : actually strip_tags is safe, it's the html you input to it that needs to be checked though - since it is based on regular expressions... and if the HTML is faulty then youh have a bigger problem then stripping tags

Comment: No, strip_Tags is NOT safe, it doesn't take into account attributes at all, so <b onmouseover="xss()"> would parse fine.

Comment: would everybody please stop inssisting on the fact that `strip_tags()` is not safe - that is just not true. the only thing that is not safe is the html you send to it, and the validation part is your responsibility - not the function's

Comment: Ok let us know some sites where you use strip_tags() and we'll have some fun.

Answer (score 0):

It needs a simple logic to implement, something like below:

 1. Create a list of html tags which you DON't want to escape.

 2. Intercept an html tag (opening or closing). 

 3. If the tag is not present in your list, replace the surrounding angle brackets (<>) with &lt; and &gt;, i.e. <mytag> becomes &lt; mytag &gt;

 4. Repeate this for all the tags in your html file.